# I removed some of the black metallic covering of my pan, is it still safe to use?

Tags: cleaning, cookware

I have a Seagull "4 star" "Marathon" "non-stick cookware" pan.
I have decoated much of the black metallic coating of that pan with a [stainless metallic scotch brite](https://www.google.com/search?q=stainless%20metallic%20scotch%20brite&rlz=1C1CHBD_enTH852TH852&sxsrf=ACYBGNTFLIZwK9kLunVh2doHvbJ0UhiBXQ:1579958962840&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjpnPXl7Z7nAhX073MBHetIBHYQ_AUoAXoECA0QAw&biw=1536&bih=722).

I made the above decoating the above after a few months in which the pan had some `matt black` carbonated stain with some scratches in it, which kept staying there insistently and no liquid soa[ liquid-soap marination with *gentle cloth scotch brite* wiping helped.

[image]

### My problem

First, I am not sure it is still safe to use and second, after removal, one might be able to see a new, even bigger such black "carbonated" stain, appearing around the newly exposed metal.

### My question

I removed some of the black metallic covering the pan (and now one part of the metal is exposed and another became blacker → `matt black`), is it still safe to use?

### Update

I tried to pour some well refined sunflower oil and heat it, then most of the uncovered metallic part became yellow (I have no idea how to explain it); this yellowishness didn't come down with a napkin → why wouldn't it?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the close-up, I'd say that the 'black stain' is where the actual non-stick Teflon coating has already been scratched off.
The bare metal is where you finished the job & also removed the substrate, which was probably used to get the Teflon to stick to the aluminium.

I think you've reached the point where it's simpler to just throw it in the recycle & buy a new one.
Treat it more gently next time - **never** use metal utensils or scourers on Teflon. Non-Stick tends to only be good for a couple of years at best, so you need to weigh up how much you're willing to spend on one… every couple of years.

Answer (score 2):

Safe is relative, I personally wouldn't use it anymore.

You've scrubbed off the non-stick coating in one spot, and damaged a lot of the coating in the area around it. The damaged area is going to flake off and go into your food if you cook with it. Some non stick coatings like perfluorooctanoic acid (PFOA) may be carcinogenic, although they've been mostly phased out. Polytetrafluorethylene (C2F4), aka Teflon shouldn't be a problem to ingest, but do you really want to?

Also, you've exposed the bare aluminum underneath the coating. There doesn't seem to be any scientific consensus on whether bare aluminum is bad for you or not (anodized or coated is fine but this isn't anymore), but bare aluminum reacts with acids and can lead to off flavors in the food, which is something to avoid.

You are better off getting a new pan.

Comment: Teflon is inert and harmless -- in fact it's one of the most inert things you can swallow.  This is why teflon is sometimes used to coat surgical devices.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94619/is-teflon-a-poison-if-ingested

Comment: The teflon shouldn't be a problem, but now the aluminium can leach into food